# Will the authorities arrest somone who uses banned apps in Qatar?

Tags: censorship

My father is working in Qatar. I instructed him to download Signal Messenger because IMO has advertisements and it interrupts our video calling persistently.

As I search on the web about Signal's Censorship Circumvention, read some articles, it says, "At the point of writing, Signal is banned in Egypt, Oman, Iran Qatar, and the UAE." The article was written on January 16, 2021. My father installed the Signal Messenger two weeks ago.

Will he be arrested for using Signal Messenger? 'Cause, it is banned in Qatar and I don't know how the government law works there.

Comment: It certainly seems not worth the risk just to avoid advertising

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### They might

In any event, signal is blocked in Qatar so it won’t work. Unless you use a VPN. Which means, in legal terms, unless you take deliberate and intentional steps to circumvent the law in Qatar.

Qatari authorities don’t look kindly on this.

At best, your father will have his device confiscated and then be deported. The police may beat him up a bit because they can, the judiciary has no practical oversight over the police in Qatar.

At worst, he might get caned and jailed for a few years.

Or, he might get away with it. He can do the cost benefit analysis.